# What sort of lab can determine PAH concentration in a soil or charcoal sample? How difficult is it to do?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, toxicity

Non-chemist here.  I'm curious how difficult it is to determine concentration of PAH in a sample of soil or powdered charcoal, or a sample of the two mixed together.

What would be involved in doing so?

Is it particularly specialized, or the sort of thing that any trained chemist could do?

Is it particularly difficult?  Costly?  Specialized?  Or would most any chemistry lab have the tools to do it?

Any idea if there are any commercial labs where samples can be shipped for analysis?  Anywhere in the world, or in the US in particular?

Comment: It is most likely done using chromatomass-spectrometry of toluene extract. Extract itself is pretty easy to make, but finding chromatomass-spectrometer tuned for specific needs is probably hard. Large chemical universities, oil and coal chemical plant should have proper facilities.

Comment: @permeakra I'd say if you can ballpark a cost (reagents, time, etc.) that's a great answer.

Comment: @jonsca The time is AFAIK reasonable, no more then a day for the analysis itself, no idea for other procedures. I'm not aware of the exact cost, this is why I posted a comment =). While materials used (liquid nitrogen for the mass-spectrometer, carrier for chromatographer) cannot cost much, the cost of the hardware, software and mass-spectrum library to identify components is likely to be high, so it must cost something. I guess it should be ~100-1000 dollars, but this is only a guess, and an uninformed one.

Comment: @permeakra Gotcha.  Well, we'll see if someone else has a better idea of those costs.  It might even work to say that it varies based on the volume of tests that the institution performs or something (since it's something that's going to vary by region, anyway).

Comment: Thanks folks for the ideas.  Any idea how common a procedure it is?  Are there any sorts of labs for which it'd be routine?